# StandardColorMap in MainMenu

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Hey guys. I have a problem with StandardColorMap and MainMenu. I need to create ColorMap in one submenu. How to do it?

P.S.
I am programming with delphi 2007

Comment: That's really not much to go on.  Can you be a bit more specific as to what you're trying to do?

Comment: In MainMenu's submenu I would like to put color selection :) Is that posible?

Comment: http://yfrog.com/7estandardcolormapj Here is where i want put that colormap

Answer (score 0):

first create the menuitems. then you have to use the canvas given by the OnDrawItem event of the menuItems ([here'is a good explanation and use case](http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/a/owner_drawing.htm)).
one idea is to store the TColor value as integer in the Tag property. Then when OnClick is triggered, the color selected is the one in the Tag of the Sender, which is a TMenuItem.